# Scouts-Many-Marshes will not move to Breezehome

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just married him, and when I told him to move to Whiterun, he just stands in the same exact spot he was standing in when I told him to move. He'll only leave Riften if I tell him to move into his house. (Probably the Argonian Assemblage in Wimdhelm) How can I make him move to my house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by fast traveling, and after a while he just appeared in my house.

Comment: If you have solved your issue, you can answer your own question by hitting the green check mark. This will show people that your question has been answered.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days.